# Find a record from a large no of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table called Route which is having a attribute mile.

I have to find all the routes whose miles is in between 0-15 but the problem is the route table is having 75k records and its taking a long time to load.

Can anyone help me out with a better approach for doing this.

Comment: Try adding index for the mile column for the route and check if there is any increase in the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Index` for the mile column and `find_each` to find out the results:

```
Route.find_each(batch_size: 2000,:conditions => {:mile => 0..15})
```